# Windows CE CAB file creation does not like spaces in file path

Tags: compact-framework, cab, windows-server-2012-r2, cabwiz

We've just set up a new development server, and when building our existing mobile applications (Windows Mobile 6.5), I'm getting the following error:

```
Windows CE CAB Wizard

Warning: Section [RegKeys] has no data
Warning: Section [DefaultInstall] key "AddReg" - there are no section entries to process
Error: CAB file "E:\...\MyProject.CAB" could not be created

ERROR: The Windows CE CAB Wizard encountered an error.  See the output window for more information.
```

Now, I've worked out that it's due to spaces in the file paths. Which, I can fix, but is a tedious task as we have multiple mobile applications that will need changing. We also have spaces in our default dev folder paths, so all programmers would need to make a change to their dev environment.

The new dev machine is running Windows Server 2012 R2, the old one was Server 2008 R2. Both using VS2008. Nothing has changed in the source code, so it has to be something different with the OS version...?

I've read many posts with this same issue, but have not found any explanation as to why it is happening, just fixing the spaces.

I'd prefer to be able to find a magic system setting that makes it allow spaces in file paths again!

Comment: I have not read about problems with spaces in path for cabWizard. Cam you post where the cab should be created, the inf file and the cabWizard command line you use. Possibly not a probme with the spaces but with access rights?

Comment: Thanks @josef, I can give more detail tomorrow when I'm back in the office, but I'm not sure access rights is the prob (will look into this further tomorrow, however...). I modified the folder paths to no longer have spaces (including paths in vdproj files - again, will follow up with more detail...), rebuilt the solution, and the associated CABs compiled successfully. Hence why I'm pretty certain it's to do with the spaces!

Comment: Possibly you reach the line limit inside the inf file (about 128 byte). So you can not create a cab with long path names inside the inf file.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the delay...So, I have appropriate access to the folder (not "Full Control", but Modify, Read & Write, List Folder Contents, Read and Write)...

Comment: The command when I capture it through Task Manager during the build process is:
    "c:\...\cabwiz.exe" "E:\Users\Brad$\wf\MyAppName\MyCabProjectName\Debug\MyCabProjectName.inf" /dest "E:\Users\Brad$\wf\MyAppName\MyCabProjectName\Debug\" /err CabWiz.log /compres

And the .inf file has 161 lines...

But all of this is exactly the same as the previous dev server - even down to the file path. The only difference I can see is the OS version..

Comment: Did you use the same path's for all involved tools and files? Dd you change the environment memory reservation? Just try with some shorter path by copying the files to another dir and start cabwiz with the shorter path and file names.